# Função max E Cast JUnta Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, servidor, sql-server-2008

Estou precisando converter um campo de Nvarchar para Float em um pesquisa, e pegar o valor mais alto.

esta função funciona

```
SELECT MAX(valor) 
from [Enops].[dbo].[Tbl_Pulsomedia15_Vazao_Eta_B_Bentes]
Where valor <> 'processando'  and valor <> 'Perda de Sinal'.
```

mas na hora que coloco o max fala que não é uma função do sql server

```
SELECT Max (cast(valor as nvarchar(200))AS FloatValue) 
from[Enops].[dbo].[Tbl_Pulsomedia15_Vazao_Eta_B_Bentes]
```

teria alguma forma de fazer isto?

Answer (score 0):

resolvido

```
SELECT MAX(cast(replace(convert(varchar,ltrim(rtrim(valor))),',','.') as float)) AS Maximo, 
       MIN(cast(replace(convert(varchar,ltrim(rtrim(valor))),',','.') as float)) AS Mínimo 
From [Enops].[dbo].[Tbl_Pulsomedia15_Vazao_Eta_B_Bentes] 
Where valor <> 'processando'  and valor <> 'Perda de Sinal'
```